# Javascript CORS JSON/JSONP Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have browsed most CORS and JSON request topics, and cannot understand why this first script works, but not the second. I would love to be educated in the ways of CORS and Javascript and XMLHTTPRequest2 and AJAX.

This works:

```
function wfs() {
 var url = 'http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/51.22545,4.40730,%5B51.22,4.41,51.2,4.41%5D,51.23,4.42/car.js?lang=de&units=miles&callback=getRoute';
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type="text/javascript";
 script.src=url;
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

function getRoute(response) {
 console.log(response);
}
```

This does not work:

```
function wfs() {
 var url = 'http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/51.22545,4.40730,%5B51.22,4.41,51.2,4.41%5D,51.23,4.42/car.js?lang=de&units=miles';
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', url, true);
 xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var json = this.response;
    console.log(json);
  }
 };

 xhr.send();
}
```

Firebug shows a Red 200 Null Response.

However, the second script does work when I use a different url:

```
var url = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/?mime=2';
```

Comment: You `cloudmade.com` response probably doesn't send CORS permission with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so the requesting origin is not allowed to read the resource contents. However, `<script>` tags allow you to *execute* cross-origin script resources without CORS permission (but not *read* their contents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first domain, `http://routes.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/0.3/51.22545,4.40730,%5B51.22,4.41,51.2,4.41%5D,51.23,4.42/car.js?lang=de&units=miles`, does not implement CORS (i.e. does not send a usable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header).  `http://ip.jsontest.com/?mime=2` does.  There is nothing you can do about this -- it depends on the server.

The first block of code uses JSONP.  What this actually does is inject a script tag into the document.  Script tags can have external sources (if they are not of the same scheme, they may be blocked for security reasons).  This allows the server to essentially send you javascript code that you insert into a `<script>` that gets run immediately.

Comment: I understand the callback with JSONP, that's how I wiggled it around to work. http://cloudmade.com/documentation/routing tells me the service returns either JSON or GPX format. If it does not allow CORS, how are scripts/applications supposed to query without each time manually typing in the lat/long parameters? Is it that applications execute code outside of a browser, so there are less checks on 'cross-domain' requests?

Comment: @Barrett I don't understand your actual questions.  What do you mean "without manually typing in the lat/long parameters?"  How else would you do it?  I also don't know what you mean by "less checks on cross-domain requests," or how those two questions are even associated

Comment: I apologize for the lack of context. The url you see is hard-coded for testing purposes, I am using leafletjs on a website to grab the lat/long location when a user clicks the map. I send this request to cloudmade to get the route which I parse and turn into a line feature on the  map, from point A to B. Clarification is hard after you have given me your answer. I am satisfied. In the future, I will be more broad with my initial question. Thank you for your input.